# Make a folder name %prevMonth%"-"%prevYear=%"-01" using batch (.bat) files

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a folder naming it to the previous month. But my code does not seem to work. Here is my code.

```
@echo off

for /F "tokens=1,3 delims=-" %%a in ("%date%") do (
   set prevYear=%%a
   set month=%%b
)
if "%month:~0,1%" equ "0" set month=%month:~1%
set /A prevMonth=month-1
if "%prevMonth%" equ "0" (
   set /A prevMonth=12, prevYear-=1
)
if %prevMonth% lss 10 set prevMonth=0!prevMonth!

mkdir %prevMonth%"-"%prevYear%"-01"
```

Any help please.

**EDIT:**
Base on comment.

Comment: What output are you getting? `%prevYear=%` is not a valid variable name; it should be `%prevYear%`.

Comment: @SomethingDark No folder is created.

Comment: Should it not read, `mkdir "%prevMonth%-%prevYear%-01"`?

Comment: You're setting variables inside of `for` loops, which means you need to use delayed expansion.

Comment: @SomethingDark i tried setting delayed expansion but it still wont work. I will be reading your link now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here'e an alternative using PowerShell:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F UseBackQ %%A In (
    `PowerShell "(Get-Date).AddMonths(-1).ToString('yyy-MM')"`
) Do If Not Exist "%%A-01\" MD "%%A-01"
```